# Electron + AngularJS Views not found

Tags: angularjs, node.js, electron

I am trying to develop a desktop application using Electron. I am also using AngularJS.

The problem I am running into is that when I create a custom directive, and load a templateUrl, the view doesn't load and the console says it doesn't exist. Yes, the path is correct, I am sure of it.

The problem is that the application is already running index.html, so it can't load the second file. Needless to say, I am not experienced enough to solve this problem on my own.

I know that Electron uses node on the backend, so I suppose setting routes and/or setting a path to my static files might resolve the problem, but I don't know how to do it.

I have searched the whole web for a solution, but I couldn't find a clear answer.

Comment: I just found out that it can't load images as well, so that proves my theory that I have to set some sort of path to my static files. But how...?

Answer (score 0):

One way you could easily do it, is by adding your template as an inline template on the angular side, for example in your `index.html`:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="temp1.html">
    ....
</script>
```

Then you can reference it from your directive, like `templateUrl: temp1.html`.

Otherwise, you could also use a module bundler. Webpack has a [ng-template loader](https://github.com/WearyMonkey/ngtemplate-loader) which does that for you. Gulp and Grunt also have equivalents

Another thing to try, if you need to reference paths from the js side, is to use `__dirname` nodejs variable. [Here an example](https://github.com/RinatMullayanov/angular-boilerplate/blob/electron/src/app.config.js)

Comment: As per what you've mentioned about images, it seems that was a bug, that in latests versions of Electron seem to be solved: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/1747

Comment: I don't think it's a bug, just my lack of knowledge. I had similar problems when I was going through the MEAN stack. I ended up fixing the problem back then by simply setting a path to my static files using express. But it makes no sense to use it here.

Comment: I am taking a look at the ng-template loader. I can't make it work, though. Shouldn't this work? Or am I doing something wrong? const navbarView = require('!ngtemplate?relativeTo=/navbar/!html!/navbar.html');